# cover/image that will hide a UIButton, but still let it be touched

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton, alpha

Any ideas on how to create a cover that has alpha 100 but is able to let a button behind it be touched, and an action to be called.

i dont want to apply the action to the cover, nor change the buttons image - as a convaluted set up is required for each one.

any ideas? what im after is effective not a see-through button, but a touch through button...

Cheers in advance guys

sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cover's [`userInteractionEnabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW50) to NO.